# Spring 3.0.5 doesn't evaluate @Value annotation from properties

Tags: spring, frameworks, properties, autowired

Trying to auto-wire properties to a bean in *Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE*, I'm using:

- `config.properties`:

  ```
  username=myusername
  ```
- `main-components.xml`:

  ```
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />
  ```
- MyClass:

  ```
  @Service
  public class MyClass {

      @Value("${username}")
      private String username;
      ...
  }
  ```

As a result, username gets set to *literally* `"${username}"`, so the expression doesn't get parsed. My other auto-wired dependencies on this class get set, and Spring doesn't throw any exception. I also tried to add `@Autowired` but it didn't help.

If I parse properties to a separate bean and then use `@Autowired` + `@Qualifier`, it works:

```
<bean id="username" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${username}"/>
</bean>
```

Any ideas how to use just `@Value`? Maybe I need to include some Spring dependency that I haven't? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you have `<context:property-placeholder>` in the same application context as your `MyClass` bean (not in the parent context)?

Comment: You're right. I moved <context:property-placeholder> from context defined by ContextLoaderListener to servlet context. Now my values get parsed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: quite a useful thing to do here is to set ignore-unresolvable-placeholders to false - thus the application will fail if it cannot resolve place holders - which is what your problem was

Comment: Found this answer after many hours of wondering why my @Value annotations weren't working :( As mentioned in [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890544/spring-value-annotation-in-controller-class-not-evaluating-to-value-inside-pro) BeanPostProcessor is not shared accross containers even in same hierachy

Comment: You can @Autowire Environment and then environment.getProperty("name"). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15562319/632293

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found what the issue was. Copy/paste from comments:

Are you sure you have `<context:property-placeholder>` in the same application context as your MyClass bean (not in the parent context)? – axtavt

You're right. I moved `<context:property-placeholder>` from the context defined by the `ContextLoaderListener` to the servlet context. Now my values get parsed. Thanks a lot! - alex