# Properties file not getting loaded

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, autowired

I have Two projects, CarpoolDB and Carpool.

CarpoolDB : contains backend stuff and has

carpool-application-context.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.onmobile" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:server.properties" />
```

server.properties

```
cm.db.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
cm.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carpool1
cm.db.username=abc
cm.db.password=xyz
```

I make a jar of carpoolDB and place in Carpool Application

Carpool: contains UI thing and for backend contact carpoolDB jar and has

carpool-application-context1.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:carpool-application-context.xml"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.onmobile.carpool.authentication" />
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:carpool.properties" /> 

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.onmobile.carpool.controller, com.onmobile.carpool.util" />
```

carpool.properties

```
cm.email.sender.mail.smtp.host=mail.on.com
```

Now, I have one class com.onmobile.carpool.util.EmailSender, it has one property smtpHost and want the value to get injected by Spring using @Value but it is not getting injected.

```
@Controller
public class EmailSender {

    public static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(EmailSender.class);

    @Value("${cm.email.sender.mail.smtp.host}")
    private String smtpHost;

}
```

I am getting error as

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'cm.email.sender.mail.smtp.host'
```

carpool.properties is present in src folder.

Why it is not picking the cm.email.sender.mail.smtp.host from carpool.properties file. is there any relation with properties file present in jar file.

Actually properties file is loaded as I can't see in logs like file not found but field is not getting autowired.

---

---

Posting updated complete configuration files after removing import

web.xml

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/carpool-application-context1.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

carpool-application-context1.xml

```
<!-- Configure annotated beans --> 
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.onmobile.carpooldb.db" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:carpool.properties" />


   <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName"><beans:value>${cm.db.driverClassName}</beans:value></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="url"><beans:value>${cm.db.url}</beans:value></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="username"><beans:value>${cm.db.username}</beans:value></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="password"><beans:value>${cm.db.password}</beans:value></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="testOnBorrow"><beans:value>true</beans:value></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="testOnReturn"><beans:value>true</beans:value></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="validationQuery"><beans:value>select 1</beans:value></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="maxIdle"><beans:value>-1</beans:value></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="maxActive"><beans:value>-1</beans:value></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements"><beans:value>-1</beans:value></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="maxWait"><beans:value>30000</beans:value></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    //session factory bean and other configuration
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:carpool.properties" />

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.onmobile.carpool.authentication, com.onmobile.carpool.controller, com.onmobile.carpool.util" />


<!-- Declare a view resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

carpool.properties

```
cm.db.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
cm.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carpool
cm.db.username=abc
cm.db.password=xyz

user.profile.pic.base.folder=D:\\carpoolRepository\\carpoolProfilePicUpload
google.places.autocomplete.response.xml.base.folder=D:\\carpoolRepository\\googleMapXML

#EMAIL - FORGOT PASSWORD 
cm.email.sender.mail.smtp.host=mail.on.com
```

I am trying to inject value of  cm.email.sender.mail.smtp.host in EmailSender "smtpHost" property way mentioned above, when i read it it says null.
other properties like cm.db.driverClassName etc get properly injected in carpool-application-context1.xml.

I am attaching the snap containing location for configuration files[image]

Comment: Are you getting the same exception?

Comment: consider posting an update for the question with the actual web.xml and configuration files

Comment: Thanks for your help Boris. I have updated my post with all configuration files. Also i am not getting any exception but EmailSender "smtpHost" property is not injected by correct value.

Answer (score 3):

You have `<context:component-scan base-package="com.onmobile" />`  in the `carpool-application-context.xml` which is imported from `carpool-application-context1.xml` so that forces your controller to be created in the root web app context, because `"com.onmobile"` includes `"com.onmobile.carpool.controller"`, and there is no `property-placeholder` config for [the root context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890544/spring-value-annotation-in-controller-class-not-evaluating-to-value-inside-pro/11891396#11891396).

You have a property placeholder configurer in the servlet context(spring-servlet.xml). Property placeholder configurers(defined by the `context:property-placeholder` tag) are bean postprocessors and work on per container basis, so they can't modify the bean definitions of context they are not defined in. So it can't modify the bean definition of controller instance declared in the root context(carpool-application-context.xml, carpool-application-context1.xml). So because of the double scanning your controller is created twice - both in root and servlet context, and only one is processed by the correct placeholder configurer.

As a fix, you can use filter expressions in component-scan to pick up `@Controller` annotated classes only only in the `spring-servlet.xml`, and exclude it from `carpool-application-context.xml`/`carpool-application-context1.xml`

See [@Service are constructed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4335438/241986) for examples of filters

Please keep your Spring configuration simple, your configuration is very puzzling.

**update** you are confusing controllers (which are annotated with `@Controller` and I think should be better put into `aaa.bbb.controllers` package) with services which should be annotated with `@Service` in the `util` package. My advice is to move your services to the root web app context(carpool-application-context1.xml) and put the property placeholder configurer declaration there.

Comment: _"Please keep your Spring configuration simple, your configuration is very puzzling."_

+1 to that.

Comment: Hey Boris, Thanks for explaining and pointing to references which helped in getting the problem but still i am not very clear. can you please elaborate your first paragraph....please it will be lot helpful...thanks

Comment: It seems that the tag has been swallowed by the markdown, I'll fix it when I get to PC. The problem is that the first configuration file scans "com.onmobile" and that includes your controller class that has value annotation. Configurer is not defined in the root context(which processes appcontext and appcontext1 files), the situation is the similar as in the first link of the answer. No placeholder configurer in the root context, the configurer in servlet context can't do anything with the controller mistakingly created in the root context because postprocessors work on per app context basis.

Comment: Hey Boris, really appreciated for your quick reply.I have restructured my app and now i have only carpool-application-context1.xml with data     <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.onmobile.carpooldb.db" />
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:carpool.properties" /> and spring-servlet.xml with data     <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:carpool.properties" /><context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.onmobile.carpool.authentication,com.onmobile.carpool.controller, com.onmobile.carpool.util"/>

Comment: still I am facing issue of @Value not working. what i should do to make it work.

Comment: You need to have the property placeholder configurer in the same app context where the controller declared.

Comment: Are you sure that carpool-application-context.xml is out of the game?