# How do I set a property on a bean annotated with @Component after creation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

I have an annotated bean with `@Component` that gets built using `<context:component-scan/>`, however I wish to set a boolean property after this has been created from a value within a properties file using `<context:property-placeholder/>`.

Comment: Annotate the field with `@Value("propertyName")`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890544/spring-value-annotation-in-controller-class-not-evaluating-to-value-inside-pro

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis. Please make an answer and I shall accept it.

Comment: Too late :). Happy you got it.

Comment: LOL no that's not what I was getting at. Give him the answer, I don't care about points as long as you solved your problem.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if you add an answer, I  will delete mine. you did answer first after all. I just wanted the question to show up as having been answered in the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate the field with `@Value("propertyName")`.

See related question: [Spring @Value annotation in @Controller class not evaluating to value inside properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890544/spring-value-annotation-in-controller-class-not-evaluating-to-value-inside-pro)