# Where do I put a property that every @Controller can read/access in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

Where do I put a property that every @Controller can read/access in Spring MVC?

For example, I want to set a flag such as DEBUG_MODE = 1, then read this flag from my code to do something.

Answer (score 1):

You may use spring @Value annotation and put the property in the properties file check out this question [Spring @Value annotation in @Controller class not evaluating to value inside properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890544/spring-value-annotation-in-controller-class-not-evaluating-to-value-inside-pro)

answer by Boris Treukhov

Comment: Thank you Boris, I will check and learn for how to use this @Value.