# how can i access properties file filed using applicationcontext.xml file in spring?

Tags: java, spring, maven, applicationcontext

i added following in my applicationContext File

```
        <bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:stage.properties</value>
                    <value>classpath:environment.properties</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

where i need to access  stage.properties file values .stage.properties file is in src/main/resources

i have written following line in my java class to access this file

```
         @Value("${spring.username}")
         private String usr;
```

but i am getting valu for usr is like =${spring.username}
what i am missing here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890544/spring-value-annotation-in-controller-class-not-evaluating-to-value-inside-pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Value("${spring.username}") notation requires the use of PropertyPalceholderConfigurer / PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer depending on Spring version to resolve property placeholder. Either

Solution 1

Replace

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:stage.properties</value>
                    <value>classpath:environment.properties</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

with

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:stage.propertes,classpath:environment.properties"/>
```

Make sure to import the Spring context namespace

Solution 2.

Use SpEL to access your properties bean with @Value as follows

```
@Value("#{properties['spring.username']}
private String usr;
```

This will access the spring.username property of the properties bean in your context