# Spring: Why does Bean resolve as null during injecting?

Tags: java, spring, cxf

Collegues, i have a bean:

```
    @Component
    public class BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor extends SoapHeaderInterceptor {

        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor.class);

        @Value("#{${accepted.username.pass1}}")
        private Map<String,String> authMap;

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
            AuthorizationPolicy policy = message.get(AuthorizationPolicy.class);

            if (policy == null) {
                sendErrorResponse(message, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
                return;
            }

            String username = policy.getUserName();
            String password = policy.getPassword();

            // CHECK USERNAME AND PASSWORD
            if (!checkLogin(username,password)) {

                 sendErrorResponse(message, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
            }
        }

        public boolean checkLogin(String username, String password) {
            MapUtils.debugPrint(System.out, "Map: " , authMap);

            if (authMap.containsKey(username.trim()) && password.trim().equals(authMap.get(username).trim())) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
   //some other methods
    }
```

When i run test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = SpumConfig.class)
public class BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptorTest {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptorTest.class);

    @Autowired
    BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor basicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor;
    @Test
    public void handleMessage() throws Exception {
       log.info(String.valueOf(basicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor.checkLogin("abc", "321")));
    }}
```

I receive `true` and `MapUtils.debugPrint` method prints all keys and values:

> Map: =  {
>       abc = 325 java.lang.String
>       cda = 322 java.lang.String
>       sss = Bas3 java.lang.String } java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap

But when i compile a jar file, run application and than call web service I recieve

```
Map:  = null
```

Why does it happen and how correctly inject map into `BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor`?

**Update**

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.comp.spum"})
    @PropertySource("classpath:spum-${env}.properties")
    public class spumConfig {
      private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(spumConfig.class);

        @Autowired
        Environment environment;
        @Autowired
        spumCommons spumCommons;


  @Bean
    public String appProps() {
        log.info("test.db.url = " + environment.getProperty("test.db.url"));
        return null;
    }

    @Bean public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
    { return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();}

    }
```

**Update 2**

According to log properties are resolving and  `basicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor` was created:

> 2017-08-22 10:25:00,573 [main] DEBUG
>   o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of
>   bean 'basicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor': AutowiredFieldElement for
>   private java.util.Map
>   com.comp.spum.service.interceptors.BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor.authMap
>   2017-08-22 10:25:00,574 [main] TRACE
>   o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key
>   'accepted.username.pass1' in [environmentProperties] 2017-08-22
>   10:25:00,574 [main] TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver -
>   Searching for key 'accepted.username.pass1' in [systemProperties]
>   2017-08-22 10:25:00,574 [main] TRACE
>   o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key
>   'accepted.username.pass1' in [systemEnvironment] 2017-08-22
>   10:25:00,574 [main] TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver -
>   Searching for key 'accepted.username.pass1' in [class path resource
>   [spum-dev.properties]] 2017-08-22 10:25:00,574 [main] DEBUG
>   o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key
>   'accepted.username.pass1' in [class path resource
>   [spum-dev.properties]] with type [String] 2017-08-22 10:25:00,574
>   [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key
>   'accepted.username.pass1' in [environmentProperties] with type
>   [String] 2017-08-22 10:25:00,574 [main] TRACE
>   o.s.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper - Resolved placeholder
>   'accepted.username.pass1' 2017-08-22 10:25:00,595 [main] DEBUG
>   o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of
>   bean 'basicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor'

Comment: You need to post your `SpumConfig.class`. We need to see your Spring configuration.

Comment: @William, I add it, but it is empty at the current moment.

Comment: You are sure that the archive you are building contains the properties file, right?

Comment: Maybe try one of the answers from this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937592/spring-value-is-not-resolving-to-value-from-property-file

Add this to your configuration:

`@Bean 
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}`

Comment: @William, I am sure about placement of properties file: If I add  `@Bean
    public String appProps() {log.info("test.db.url = " + environment.getProperty("test.db.url")); return null;}` the programm print out `test.db.url = jdbc:..` when run.

Comment: @William, also i add `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean.

Comment: When you build the archive, where are the properties being placed? Are they in the classes folder?

Comment: Yes, properties in the root of jar.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly the jar is not picking up the right path of the property file to begin with. Please validate the path of the property file first.

Then use the spring' [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to add the right path. You can validate if your application picks up the property file in the server logs when you deploy your application.

Comment: Nilsaw,  I am sure that properties is picking up because there is info about it in the log `2017-08-24 09:45:04,848 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'accepted.username.pass1' in [class path resource [spectrum-dev.properties]] with type [String]
2017-08-24 09:45:04,848 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'accepted.username.pass1' in [environmentProperties] with type [String]
2017-08-24 09:45:04,849 [main] TRACE o.s.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper - Resolved placeholder 'accepted.username.pass1'`