# where does spring look for values with the @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

In java/spring, when you use the @Value annotation to insert values into a field, where exactly does the application look for these values? I have read up and I keep seeing that it looks for a "properties file" but is there a specific name/format this file needs to have, or a certain directory this file needs to be in?

Comment: Does this help? [Spring @Value is not resolving to value from property file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937592/spring-value-is-not-resolving-to-value-from-property-file)

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? Have you tried adding a key-value in `\src\main\resources\application.properties` and then reading it in your class? Something like `app.db.name=ABC` in `application.properties` and then reading it in your class using `@Value(value = "${app.db.name}") private transient String dbName;`?

Comment: Are you using Boot? (You should if you can.) https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

Answer (score 1):

If you `don't give any specific path` thn it will use default path :

```
\src\main\resources\application.properties
```

You can also give specific path :

```
@propertySource("file:properties/application.properties")
```

Here properties folder is on same level of src folder. You can put your property file anywhere.

Hope this will work!

Comment: in the first path you gave, will that work if the file is application.yml? (in the resources folder)